# how to integrate multiple jenkins pipelines's work

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

we have pipleline A and B for Network element A+B's CI/CD work, and both works fine.

We would like to integrate product level CI/CD frame work and want to reuse pipelien A/B jenkinsfile, so we create new pipeline C and call parallel "build job" for A & B. "build job" command will trigger pipeline A/B in parallel, but build/test result is tracked in pipeline A & B, and pipleline C has no idea for that, and if need generate report for C's job, need analyze all the output by A and B seperately and re-org the report.

i'm not sure if there any other way to perform this handy work,  and this would be common issue for product level integration.

thanks for any suggestions or hint.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest instead of having A/B as separate jobs, have them as separate groovy scripts and include them inside job C in the places you need, or even better have A/B functional covered in shared libraries and use them inside C whenever it is needed.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, this way would be more efficient.